# With the E = {under $z = x^2 - y^2$, above unit circle} as the region, is my double integral setup right?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

As the title says, i'm having some trouble setting up this region, my attempts goes as follows:

Plotting $z = x^2 - y^2$ shows me the symmetries (if you didn't see them from the equation). Now looking from above and straight down we see the regions where the condition is met: $\theta \in [-\pi/4,\pi/4]\cup[3\pi/4,5\pi/4]$.
Switching to polar coordinates gives us: $z = r^2\cos(2\theta)$.
Setting up the integral should be something like:

$$2 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{1} r^2\cos(2\theta)r\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{1}{2}$$

Now my book tells me this should be $\frac{1}{8}$, can anyone point out my mistake(if there is any)?

p.s. Completely new to Latex so forgive me for my bad integrals!:)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any mistakes; but can you clarify the question? Are you supposed to find the volume of $E$ (that's what you did and it looks good) or do you have to integrate a specific function over that region?

Comment: Yes i'm supposed to find the volume of E, but since i'm getting an answer that is not like the one in my book i keep thinking that i have the integration bounds wrong which means i have the wrong idea of $E$, however $E$ is exactly as stated.

Comment: Did the problem specify the first quadrant? That would give 1/4 of the value over the region you have taken.

Comment: No it says exactly this: "under the graph $z = x^2-y^2$ and above the circle disc $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$". Could it be an error in the book? In that case i should notify my professor:)